# How To Select all row from mysql table that contains atleast one value greater than search value?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

e.g. I want to select all the **Row** where **Data** contains value greater than or equal to 5 from the below table. i.e. Row 11,13,14 and 16.

```
╔════╦═══════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Data              ║
╠════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 10 ║ 2 or 3            ║
║ 11 ║ 5 and 6           ║
║ 12 ║ 3 or 4            ║
║ 13 ║ 5 or 6(Optional)  ║
║ 14 ║ 5                 ║
║ 15 ║ 1 or 2            ║
║ 16 ║ 6 (Optional) or 3 ║
╚════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: what data type is `data` ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the data column, what type it is and what the or, and and optional mean exactly in the context of your db.

Comment: Data type of **Data** is **varchar**. @Panther

Comment: i don't think its easy to achieve with your current situation. you should consider finding a diff way to achieve this, either change your db structure or your prob.

Comment: Data type of **Data** is **varchar**. E.g. Some mobile mobile phone has two variant. You can choose either 2GB RAM **OR** 3GB RAM (Row 1). Some mobile phone comes with two Rear camera 5MP **and** 6MP (Row 2) etc. @GustavoMagalhães

Comment: Var char is a string, and there isn't a easy way to find a number in it and comparing it numerically. You will need to program a way to find the numbers, convert them to int and them compare it to the number you want to compare. You will loose lot's of performance doing that. Maybe you want to convert it to a better structure with operand one, operand two operation and two flags for optional.

Comment: I solved this problem. Check my answer if you have any other solution after viewing my answer please let me know. BTW thank you @GustavoMagalhães

Comment: Thank u @Panther

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION explode(str VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, pos-1)) + 1),
       delim, '');


SELECT ID,REPLACE(Data,'(Optional)','') AS data FROM `Temp` WHERE data >= 5 OR TRIM(explode(explode(data,'and',1),'or',1)) >= 5 OR TRIM(explode(explode(data,'and',1),'or',2) ) >=5 OR TRIM(explode(explode(data,'and',2),'or',1) ) >=5 OR TRIM(explode(explode(data,'and',2),'or',2) ) >=5
```